How to run blue moon ensemble
I would like to ask for experience using blue moon sampling. I try an example in

https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Nuclephile_Substitution_CH3Cl_-_BM

As far as I understand, I first need to make 7 POSCAR files. Then set LBLUEOUT=.TRUE. in INCAR. After running vasp5.4, I got 7 folders. I ran scripts posted on the website. When grep b_m $i/report.$j, it returned nothing.
I am not sure if this process is correct or maybe vasp5.4 has a different format.
Can anyone share the procedure to implement blue moon sampling and analysis? Do we need to keep an arrangement of atoms for POSCAR files? My initial POSCAR is like C1-->C2-->C3...Cn, but my final POSCAR is C3-->Cn-->C2... They are messy POSCAR files with atoms that are not in order.
